# Filter list of objects, check if exists

Tags: django

I have a local database which contains objects and a remote one that should have the same values. I check for any differences every time someone refreshes certain page. I am loading remote dataset into list of objects. I am stuck at checking if someone deleted object from remote location. Deleting local one is fairly simple.

```
for row in cursor_from_pyodbc:
    w = MyModel(some_id=row[0], another_value=row[1])
    remote_objects.append(w)

for remote_object in remote_objects:
    if MyModel.objects.filter(some_id=remote_object.some_id).exists():
        ...
```

I have no idea how to do it the other way around. It seems like there is no filter function on my list of objects?

```
for local_object in MyModel.objects.all():
    if remote_objects.filter(some_id=local_object.some_id).exists():
        ...
```

It throws:

```
Exception Value:    
'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

I feel there is a simple way to do that but don't know what it is.
Requested:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    another_value = models.CharField(unique=False, max_lenght=20)
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models (`LzWidLak` and `MyModel`). Likely the filtering can be done entirely at the database side, which is usally more efficient.

Comment: `remote_objects` is a list not a `QuerySet`. You seem to be using a cursor to make the queries as `cursor_from_pyodbc` suggests, why don't you do the same to check if the remote object exists (write a query and use the cursor)? And perhaps this replication is better off being done somewhere other than Django?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `LzWidlak` is `MyModel`, forgot to change that part for better clarity. To make it simple it has only `some_id` and `another_value` as a parameters.

Comment: @Jorhanc: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remote objects is a list you connot perform queryset filter on the list

```py
for local_object in MyModel.objects.all():
    if local_object.some_id in remote_objects:
        ...
```

Assuming `remote_objects` is a list of ids. and you want to check the condition exerytime.

**I would like to suggest you a better way to get all the deleted objects at once**

```py
remote_objects = ["id1", "id2",] #List of ids
deleted_objects = MyModel.objects.exclude(id_in=remote_objects)
print(deleted_objects)
```

Again i'm assuming `remote_objects` is a list of ids, if not append append only the ids to make it a list of ids.

if `deleted_objects` queryset is empty, then no remote data is deleted, if it contains objects then the objects are the deleted remote data.